# MSChart - Show series name on x Axis

Tags: mschart

I would like the chart shown below to show the series names (700HEN, ORG 700HEN etc.) under each column rotated 90 degrees not as a legend and I want to maintain the date label for each series group (it can be rotated or left horizontal). Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Is this not possible to do? I imagined this would be a standard requirement with a simple solution. Any help greatly appreciated. One other note, I am binding the data with DataBindCrossTable, if that makes a difference.